# Problem involving limsup.

Tags: analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I had a problem while computing the limit superior below:

> If $r\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{|a_n|}\leq \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{M}$ $~~~~~~\forall n$
>   letting $n\rightarrow \infty$
>    $\implies$ $limsup$ $r\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{|a_n|}\leq 1$

But I can't get how is limsup$ \leq 1$ . Kindly help.

Comment: Can you compute $\lim_n \sqrt[n]{M}$? Recall $\sqrt[n]{M} = e^{{1 \over n} \log M}$.

Comment: @copper.hat it will be $1$ .because $e^0=1$ .

Comment: @spectraa What's then the problem? $\limsup M^{1/n}$ will be the same and $\limsup$ conserves the order of the sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that conclusion because $M$ is a fixed number.

$$limsup~ r \sqrt[n]{a_n} \le limsup ~ \sqrt[n]{M}= lim ~ \sqrt[n]{M} = 1$$